# Message not sent to gmail accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, dns, gmail

> I am sending mail from my rails app when users submit the form , mails are sent to the users except that gmail users , gmail has blocked the messages sent from the form.
>
> And mails are also gone in spam folder.
>
> Below is the response that I have got from gmail.
>
> The original message was received at Thu, 10 Dec 2015 01:09:48 -0600
>   from localhost [127.0.0.1]
>
> ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
>   
>       (reason: 550-5.7.1 [188.166.105.158      12] Our system has detected that this message is)
>   
>       (reason: 550-5.7.1 [188.166.105.158      12] Our system has detected that this message is)
>
> ----- Transcript of session follows -----
>   ... while talking to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.:
>
> > > DATA
> > >       <<< 550-5.7.1 [188.166.105.158      12] Our system has detected that this message is
> > >       <<< 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
> > >       <<< 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
> > >       <<< 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. x185si17615928wme.57 - gsmtp
> > >       554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
>
> Final-Recipient: RFC822; mail1@gmail.com
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.7.1
>   Remote-MTA: DNS; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.7.1 [188.166.105.158      12] Our system has detected that this message is
>   Last-Attempt-Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 01:09:49 -0600
>
> Final-Recipient: RFC822; mail2@gmail.com
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.7.1
>   Remote-MTA: DNS; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>   Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.7.1 [188.166.105.158      12] Our system has detected that this message is
>   Last-Attempt-Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 01:09:49 -0600
>
> any help highly appreciated thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/mail-server-help-111/gmail-blocks-messages-825511.html here might be some help u get

Answer (score 1):

I also tried google some time back but it keep blocking account due to security purpose. We don't have option if we use free account then must have to wait until the time span given by them.

Why don't you try [Postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04), it is very easy to use and can be sent bulk emails using default rails's

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Which will be very easy to setup and hassle free solution I found so far you can use it for test and production as well.

[postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04)